# PHP Regular Expression - Repeating Match of a Group

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that may look something like this:

```
$r = 'Filed under: <a>Group1</a>, <a>Group2</a>';
```

Here is the regular expression I am using so far:

```
preg_match_all("/Filed under: (?:<a.*?>([\w|\d|\s]+?)<\/a>)+?/", $r, $matches);
```

I want the regular expression to inside the `()` to continue to make matches as designated with the `+?` at the end.  But it just won't do it.  ::sigh::

Any ideas.  I know there has to be a way to do this in one regular expression instead of breaking it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php

$r = 'Filed under: <a>Group1</a>, <a>Group2</a>, <a>Group3</a>, <a>Group4</a>';

if(preg_match_all("/<a.*?>([^<]*?)<\/a>/", $r, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]); 
}

?>
```

output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Group1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Group2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Group3"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Group4"
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since you want to include the string 'Filed under' in the search to uniquely identify the match, you can try this, I'm not sure if it can be done using a single call to preg_match

```
// Since you want to match everything after 'Filed under'
if(preg_match("/Filed under:(.*)$/", $r, $matches)) {
    if(preg_match_all("/<a.*?>([^<]*?)<\/a>/", $matches[1], $matches)) {
        var_dump($matches[1]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to use the "Filed under: " flag.  While my example text was rudimentary, the actual file that I am parsing is quite complicated, and Filed under: is really the only unique identifier that I have to work with.  Fortunately, it is at the end of the file, so I can match all the way to the end.

Answer (score 12):

Just for fun here's a regex that will work with a single `preg_match_all`:

```
'%(?:Filed under:\s*+|\G</a>)[^<>]*+<a[^<>]*+>\K[^<>]*%`
```

Or, in a more readable format:

```
'%(?:
      Filed under:   # your sentinel string
    |                
      \G             # NEXT MATCH POSITION
      </a>           # an end tag
  )
  [^<>]*+          # some non-tag stuff     
  <a[^<>]*+>       # an opening tag
  \K               # RESET MATCH START
  [^<>]+           # the tag's contents
%x'
```

`\G` matches the position where the next match attempt would start, which is usually the spot where the previous successful match ended (but if the previous match was zero-length, it bumps ahead one more).  That means the regex won't match a substring starting with `</a>` until *after* it's matched one starting with `Filed under:` at at least once.

After the sentinel string or an end tag has been matched, `[^<>]*+<a[^<>]*+>` consumes everything up to and including the next start tag.  Then `\K` spoofs the start position so the match (if there is one) appears to start after the `<a>` tag (it's like a positive lookbehind, but more flexible).  Finally, `[^<>]+` matches the tag's contents and brings the match position up to the end tag so `\G` can match.

But, as I said, this is just for fun.  If you don't *have* to do the job in one regex, you're better off with a multi-step approach like the one @codaddict used; it's more readable, more flexible, and more maintainable.

[`\K` reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3C%3dpattern%29-%5CK)
[`\G` reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions)

EDIT: Although the references I gave are for the Perl docs, these features *are* supported by PHP, too--or, more accurately, by the PCRE lib.  I think the Perl docs are a little better, but you can also read about this stuff in the [PCRE manual](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt).

Comment: I didn't know about `\K`. Interesting! A small note about `\G` - you refer to the "previous match", which is OK, and to the "next match", which is a little confusing (Specially when the Perl example you've linked to is downright misleading - it *sets* the next position in code - **which is very different from the default behavior**). Simply put - `\G` refers to the position the current match was attempted to start in. It is also not accurate `</a>` will always match after `Filed under:` - it can also match on the start of the string, for example `</a>, <a>Group2</a>`: http://ideone.com/aTjrm .

Comment: (by the way, I came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982451/regex-capturing-a-repeated-group/7135730#7135730)

Comment: @Kobi: I should have left out the part about zero-length matches; too much noise, not enough signal.  Usually I just say `\G` matches the position where the previous match ended, and don't bother with the piddly details unless they're relevant to the current problem.  I mean, what are the odds the string will start with `</a>`?  I felt pretty safe with that one. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$r = 'Filed under: <a>Group1</a>, <a>Group2</a>'
$s = explode("</a>",$r);
foreach ($s as $k){
    if ($k){
        $k=explode("<a>",$k);
        print "$k[1]\n";
    }
}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
Group1
Group2
```

Comment: best or not, is up to individual. If it can be done without complicated regex , then to me its best, both for myself and for the one who maintains it.

Comment: As I explained in a comment above, I can't use explode....For one, there are instances where there is not comma and there is only one Group.  Two, while my example was simple, this is a complicated file. The <a> tag is not that simple either.  Three, I need the Filed under: attribute as using an explode would most certainly return unwanted values.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the regular expression to inside the () to continue to make matches as designated with the +? at the end.

`+?` is a lazy quantifier - it will match *as few* times as possible. In other words, just once.

If you want to match several times, you want a greedy quantifier - `+`.

Also note that your regex doesn't quite work - the match fails as soon as it encounters the comma between the  tags, because you haven't accounted for it. That likely needs correcting.

Comment: Right, I have tried with just the + quantifier.  That fails also.  And I did also think about the , [comma] to which I'm afraid I don't know how to set this, since the second or third match may or may not have a comma.  I did however try this as my attemp:
[code]
preg_match_all("/Filed under: (?:<a.*?>([\w|\d|\s]+?)<\/a>.*?)+/", $r, $matches);
[/code]

Comment: Hmmm, comments don't look very pretty.

Comment: @Senica: you can use backticks to format code in comments just like you can in questions and answers, but if the code is long or complex, you should edit your question and put it there instead. The code you included above was a bit much for a comment.

Comment: But @Anon. is right: a reluctant quantifier at the end of a regex almost never makes sense.  If you regex had been correct otherwise, that final `?` would have broken it.