# C#: Regex match closest

Tags: c#, html, regex, pattern-matching, closest

```
<table class="listProvision" class="itable">
    <tr>
        <td class="whatever">some infos</td>
        <td>some more infos</td>
        <td>13908402</td>
        <td>hello world</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="whatever">some infos</td>
        <td>some more infos</td>
        <td id="num">13908402</td>
        <td>hello world</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Given the above sample HTML, **how can I properly parse all existences of `<tr>...</tr>` between the `table` with class `listProvision`**?

I tried: `<table.*?listProvision.*?>(?:.*?<tr.*?>(.*?)</tr>)+.*?</table>`, but I can't figure out what's wrong. There is never going to be any complicated html pulled into this regex so don't worry about that.

Comment: 3000 rep here and you even consider parsing HTML with a Regex -- how have you not seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4068)?

Comment: Regular expressions are not the right approach, continue at your [peril](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392).

Comment: have you looked at using [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) also look at some of the suggestions here [Parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample how you can parse html string with [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var rows = doc.DocumentNode
              .SelectNodes("//table[@class='listProvision']/tr");
```

Then you can use `HtmlNode.InnerHtml` property to get all data between `<tr>...</tr>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `RegexOptions.Singleline` to [make dot match newline.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (your regex works already, I got it work [here](http://regexr.com?33gb4) with just the single-line flag)

2) [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982451/regex-capturing-a-repeated-group) `match.Groups["yourNamedCaptureGroup"].Captures` for your captures.