# Regex capturing repeating group in php without whitespace

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, matching, preg-match-all

I'm trying to parse strings by a regex in PHP that always have this format:
`FooBar(,[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+` or in other words, they have a start value/word followed by 1 or multiple entries, each entry is one comma (`,`), followed by 7 digits and 8 hexdec characters (digits or uppercase characters A to F).

My Regex to capture this is `/^C7(,[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+$/` which kind of works. When used in a `preg_match_all` it returns an array with two entries, the first as expected the input string, however, in the second array there's only one entry, the last matched chunk. *(see Example)*

I need to capure all the chunks matched by the capturing group. I did some research and found this answer, which seamed to be about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2205009/2989952, So I've adjusted my regex to `/(,[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+$/`, but I still only get one match. This can be tested at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/?flags=[g]&flavor=php). I then experimented some more, and found, that if I change the input string, to contain a space (or any not matched character for that matter), between the chunks, like this: `C7,22801422CFE0F63 ,2280141C5EF0F63 ,22801402EFD0F63 ,2280138C5ED0F63 ,228024329897530 ,228023829877530` and adjust the regex once again to `/(,[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+/` it does exactly as it is intended to do!

**Question**: Is there a way to achieve this, matching all the chunks in this recurring group without adding whitespaces in between? If so, how?

### **EDIT**

To illustrate the problem:
[image: No Whitespace]
*No Whitespace* https://regex101.com/r/ilkZjD/1

[image]
*Whitespace/random chars* https://regex101.com/r/mimBgz/1

**Goal**: Behaviour of second one, the one with whitespaces, but not adding the whitespaces (respectively the not matched characters).

### **EDIT 2 (hacky solution)**

I kind of found a solution, considering this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/2989952 Answer. The Regex `/(?:,)([0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})/` works for me. https://regex101.com/r/LEEFzv/1.However I'd still like a way, to match the initial `FooBar`. as that indicates the incoming string should be matched with this regex at all.
*(I know I could simply check the string in a second regex for this, I however would love to have it in one regex)*

**Example**:
Input: `'C7,22801422CFE0F63,2280141C5EF0F63,22801402EFD0F63,2280138C5ED0F63,228024329897530,228023829877530'`

Comment: `^` indicates beginning of line. Since you have only one line you had only one capture. And `$` indicates end of line. Maybe in your regex-engine it matches space as well.

Comment: All your data is one line and therefore there is no need to use `$`or `^`. Just remove it and it should work.

Comment: I'm aware of that and that's why I removed it in later attempts, as stated in the third paragraph. The regex engine is PHP7.1, if that makes a difference. However, the issue here is, that the capuring group gets overwritten instead of added.

Comment: to try it out, use "(,[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+" as regex on https://regex101.com/?flags=[g]&flavor=php with the given input. And then add a whitespace infront of any comma.

Comment: `/(?<=,)([0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+/`

Comment: Include links to regex101 instead of Pictures.

Comment: @splash58 is it better to use a positive lookbehind, than to use a group and just exclude it from the result as I did in Edit 2 ("/(?:,)([0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})/")? If so, what's the difference? Also is there a way to validate if the initial "FooBar" is there at the beginning of the string with your way?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ZvYlQ0/1

Comment: You can't test by the same expression the structure of the full string  if you want to separate groups :(

Comment: Maybe [`(?:^[^,]+|(?:[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+)`](https://regex101.com/r/0kZlPo/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird almoast, the issue with this one is, that it will match "FooBar", but also "Baz" at the beginning. I need one that only matches "FooBar"

Comment: Like [`(?:FooBar|(?:[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+)`](https://regex101.com/r/OgSjzP/1/)?

Comment: even closer! It should however only match it if there's "FooBar" infront, not optionally have it (and match it if it's there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
$in = 'C7,22801422CFE0F63 ,2280141C5EF0F63 ,22801402EFD0F63 ,2280138C5ED0F63 ,228024329897530 ,228023829877530';

preg_match_all('/(^\w+|\G)\h*(,[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})/', $in, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => C7,22801422CFE0F63
            [1] =>  ,2280141C5EF0F63
            [2] =>  ,22801402EFD0F63
            [3] =>  ,2280138C5ED0F63
            [4] =>  ,228024329897530
            [5] =>  ,228023829877530
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => C7
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ,22801422CFE0F63
            [1] => ,2280141C5EF0F63
            [2] => ,22801402EFD0F63
            [3] => ,2280138C5ED0F63
            [4] => ,228024329897530
            [5] => ,228023829877530
        )

)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(               : start group 1
  ^\w+          : beginning of line, 1 or more word characters
  |             : O
  \G            : match form this point
)               : end group 1
\h*             : 0 or more horizontal spaces
(               : start group 2
  ,             : a comma
  [0-9]{7}      : 7 digits
  [0-9A-F]{8}   : 8 hexa
)               : end group 2
```

Comment: Almoast perfect, I managed to achive exactly as I wan't with some little changes. "(?:^C7|\G)\h*(,[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})" https://regex101.com/r/WRlHrv/1

Answer (score 1):

To capture all chucks including the first part, you could try:

[`(?:FooBar|(?:[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+)`](https://regex101.com/r/OgSjzP/1)

**Explanation**

- A non capturing group `(?:`
- Match `FooBar`
- Or `|`
- You format in a on capturing group repeated one or more times `(?:[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})+`
- Close non capturing group

  [Output](https://3v4l.org/nhk4C)

Comment: Almost, The issue there is, that "FooBar" isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

ehmmm... maybe i can't understand the problem but your regex will work for the first scenario removing the trailing +

```
(,[0-9]{7}[0-9A-F]{8})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a pattern to get contiguous matches using the A flag (that means *Anchored*). The main interest is that you can extract your values and check the format of the line at the same time using a lookahead:

```
$pattern = '~
    (?!^)  # fails at the start of the string
    ( \h*,\h* (?<value>[0-9]{7}[A-F0-9]{8}) )
    # the first capture group is useful to shorten the 
    # the lookahead in the second branch.
  |
    (?<first>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=(?1)*$)
~xA';

if ( preg_match_all($pattern, $yourstring, $matches) ) {
    echo $matches['first'][0], PHP_EOL;
    print_r(array_values(array_filter($matches['value'])));
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/37VEo)

The A flag forces each match to start at the beginning of the string or at the end of the previous match.

The first branch describes a comma separated value and the second branch the start of the line.

The lookahead `(?=(?1)*$)` checks forward the structure of the line. If this one fails, no match is possible.